When reflecting on the original Greek of Matt, 28:19, what is meant by...in the name of the Father and the ... Are Father, Son, & HS names or titles?
Those who claim there is no such thing as trinity in the bible.
They believe the Father , son & holy spirit are merely titles and not names of God.

The first sentence isn't a sentence. Please provide the missing parts. ¶ "merely titles and not names" —  this implies that titles are of less value than names (e.g. "King" is less important than "Charles". Please clarify what the difference is and why one is better than the other. ¶ And for the underlying question that hasn't actually been asked, explain why it is significant whether something is a name or a title.

'Father' and 'Son' and 'Holy Spirit' distinguish between persons who would, otherwise, be indistinguishable and unidentifiable (to us who know them). Therefore they are distinctive and personal names not titles ; which titles could be taken by persons other than those characterised by them.

Names vs Titles
There is little or no debate that "Father", "Son" and Holy Spirit" (as is "Christ") are titles and not names.  Indeed, we know only the name of one of these, viz, "Jesus".
Text of Matt 28:19
The relevant part of the Greek text of Matt 28:19 is:

βαπτίζοντες αὐτοὺς εἰς τὸ ὄνομα ... = baptizing in the name ...

The word used here is ὄνομα (= "name"). It is the ordinary word for the name of someone or something such as "Jesus" (Matt 1:21, 23, 25), etc.
[Note: For those who suggest that Matt 29:19 is spurious, see Frank Luke's excellent answer here: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/12794/was-the-text-of-matthew-2819-changed ]
"In the Name of ..."
In Hebrew idiom, "in the name of ..." is consistently used to say, "on the authority of ...", or, "by the power of ..." and is used throughout the OT and NT.  Here is a short sample:

Matt 7:22 - Many will say to Me in that the day, 'Lord, Lord, did we not prophesy in Your name, and in Your name cast out demons and in your name perform many miracles?' [Note: "Lord" is a title not a name.]
Luke 19:38 - saying: "Blessed is the King who comes in the name of the Lord!" "Peace in heaven and glory in the highest!" [Again, "Lord" is a title and not a name.]
Acts 5:40 - And they were persuaded by him. And having called in the apostles, having beaten them, they commanded them not to speak in the name of Jesus, and they released them.
James 5:10 - Brothers as an example of suffering evils and of patience, take the prophets who spoke in the name of the Lord.
Col 3:17 - And all, whatever you might do in word or in deed, do all in the name of the Lord Jesus, giving thanks to God the Father through Him.

Thus, Jesus' instruction to baptize "in the Name of the Father and of the Son and of the Holy Spirit" is entirely consistent as an instruction to only baptize in the authority and power of the Father, Son and Holy Spirit.

This answer would have been a great answer, if not for the trinitarian bias.

@OldeEnglish - interesting - I never mention the trinity and only quoted the Bible at Matt 28:19.  Therefore, if my answer has a "trinitarian bias" then that is the fault of the Bible.

You imply it in your very last sentence. I was already to vote you up and actually had you voted up for a couple of minutes until I reread (first reading before my answer) your answer and then thought - Wait, what am I doing. He ruined it all with the last sentence. So then I retracted. Sorry about that.

@OldeEnglish - more interesting that my last sentence appears to agree with your first sentence.

You quantified. I didn't, as was merely repeating the text.

@OldeEnglish - what do you mean "quantified it"?

You said: ...is entirely consistent as an instruction to only baptize in the authority and power of the Father, Son and Holy Spirit.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

10 hours ago, I put an initial comment in the "Chat Room", now it will not open for some reason. Tried several times and in two different ways.

@OldeEnglish - I think you need to "join this conversation" to add comments each time.

I was just able to get in the CR, but you haven't said anything since I did, some 11 hours ago! Does that mean you are done??

@OldeEnglish - I had trouble before but have now added something

"In the name of" means by the power and authority of. If the British monarchy used "in the name of God, the Queen and Country" when it claimed territories, was this phrase taken to mean that the three were co-equal or that each was a person?
The asker stated "Those who claim there is no such thing as trinity in the bible.
They believe the Father, son & holy spirit are merely titles and not names of God".
Examining the verse cited would make evident that it does not say that the Father, the Son and holy spirit are/is a "trinity". In addition, the verse does not say that each are equal, each is eternal and that each is God.
There are verses that contain these same entities, but their meaning becomes obscure if these entities are each taken as God. Examples of these verses are,
Acts 10:38 ASV
even Jesus of Nazareth, how God anointed him with the Holy Spirit and with power: who went about doing good, and healing all that were oppressed of the devil; for God was with him.
Hebrews 9:14 ASV
how much more shall the blood of Christ, who through the eternal Spirit offered himself without blemish unto God, cleanse your conscience from dead works to serve the living God?
Consider the sense in these verses if each of these entities is God.
Acts 10:38
even God of Nazareth, how God anointed God with the God and with power: who went about doing good, and healing all that were oppressed of the devil; for God was with God
Hebrews 9:14
how much more shall the blood of God, who through the eternal God offered God without blemish unto God, cleanse your conscience from dead works to serve the living God?
The idea of a multi-person god is not existent in the verse cited by the asker.
Here are some evidence against the so called baptismal formula of Matthew 28:19.
The Catholic Encyclopedia, II, page 263:
"The baptismal formula was changed from the name of Jesus Christ to the words Father, Son, and Holy Spirit by the Catholic Church in the second century."
The Encyclopedia of Religion and Ethics:
As to Matthew 28:19, it says: It is the central piece of evidence for the traditional (Trinitarian) view.  If it were undisputed, this would, of course, be decisive, but its trustworthiness is impugned on grounds of textual criticism, literary criticism and historical criticism. The same Encyclopedia further states that: "The obvious explanation of the silence of the New Testament on the triune name, and the use of another (JESUS NAME) formula in Acts and Paul, is that this other formula was the earlier, and the triune formula is a later addition."
Hastings Dictionary of the Bible 1963, page 1015:
"The Trinity.-...is not demonstrable by logic or by Scriptural proofs,...The term Trias was first used by Theophilus of Antioch (c AD 180),...(The term Trinity) not found in Scripture..." "The chief Trinitarian text in the NT is the baptismal formula in Mt 28:19...This late post-resurrection saying, not found in any other Gospel or anywhere else in the NT, has been viewed by some scholars as an interpolation into Matthew. It has also been pointed out that the idea of making disciples is continued in teaching them, so that the intervening reference to baptism with its Trinitarian formula was perhaps a later insertion into the saying. Finally, Eusebius's form of the (ancient) text ("in my name" rather than in the name of the Trinity) has had certain advocates. (Although the Trinitarian formula is now found in the modern-day book of Matthew), this does not guarantee its source in the historical teaching of Jesus. It is doubtless better to view the (Trinitarian) formula as derived from early (Catholic) Christian, perhaps Syrian or Palestinian, baptismal usage (cf Didache 7:1-4), and as a brief summary of the (Catholic) Church's teaching about God, Christ, and the Spirit:..."




Clever use of God, Queen and Country, I must say. Way to get this Brit's attention. Although I'm a US citizen these days, I also hold a British passport, having lived the first 35 years of my life in England, but then you probably already knew that, if you've read my profile. Clever, alternative reading, of Acts 10:38 and Hebrews 9:14 too. You make no mention, however, of the likely probability of the "Baptismal Formula" having possibly been added surreptitiously, in an inauspicious attempt to advance Trinitarian theology, as advanced in my answer. Was I out of bounds? Can you comment?




@OldeEnglish The Encyclopedia of Religion and Ethics: As to Matthew 28:19, says: It is the central piece of evidence for the traditional (Trinitarian) view.If it were undisputed, this would,of course, be decisive, but its trustworthiness is impugned on grounds of textual criticism, literary criticism and historical criticism. The same Encyclopedia further states that: "The obvious explanation of the silence of the New Testament on the triune name, and the use of another (JESUS NAME) formula in Acts and Paul, is that this other formula was the earlier, and the triune formula is a later addition

Great!! Had not, for one minute, thought to look in the Catholic Encyclopedia (II) for what surely borders on - an "heretical" admission. Nor had I thought to look in the Hastings Dictionary of the Bible. Professor James T Tabor's video, that I linked to, in my answer, also references Eusebius's form of the (ancient) text, not to mention other advocates to same, who could not identify with what amounted to an unapologetic debasement of the original text. Worth your perusal. Worth anyones perusal for that matter, who earnestly seek veritable biblical accounting. Was it you that upvoted me?

@OldeEnglish. Yes sir.

This is the word of interest:

onoma: a name, authority, cause
Original Word: ὄνομα, ατος, τό
Part of Speech: Noun, Neuter
Transliteration: onoma
Phonetic Spelling: (on'-om-ah)
Definition: a name, authority, cause
Usage: name, character, fame, reputation.

I think we can acknowledge that "Father" is not a name. Nor is "Son" a name. These are titles we have for male figures.
The phrase "in the name of" is easy to misunderstand so let's take a closer look:


Here we see that the phrase "in the name of" means "by the authority of" or "acting on his behalf."
It's like when a corporate manager makes a decision or issues directives "in the name of" the company's CEO. The authority to make these decisions comes from the CEO and not the manager himself.
So, baptism "in the name of" signifies that the act is performed under the authority of, not by mere human authorization.
Jesus himself said or implied that his authority is from God the Father (John 6:38). If we look at John 16:13-14, we see that the Holy Spirit also acts under the authority of Christ.
What I conclude from this is that baptism "in the name of the Father, and of the Son, and of the Holy Spirit" is representative of acting under the unified authority of the three.

This also would have been a competent answer, if not for the trinitarian bias.

@OldeEnglish I did not mean to put any trinitarian bias so your comment surprises me. The verse mentions three titles, Father, Son and Holy Spirit, but I make no reference to the trinity. I say "unified authority" as it is all of their authorities that the text indicates we are to be baptized under.

Just like @Dottard, you make strong implication in your last sentence. You also referenced John 16:13-14, where you capitalized Holy Spirit, inferring personhood. For the record it is my understanding that the "helper" for Christ's disciples, after his ascension, is the ruach ha-kodesh, as per my answer. The personal pronoun "He" having been used with alacrity, in those verses, when "it" would have been more appropriate in translation.

Otherwise, it was a good answer.

@OldeEnglish Thank you for your feedback and for pointing out those aspects of my response. I understand your concern about potential biases. In my NKJV "Sprit" is indeed capitalized. Additionally, the OP brought in the idea of the trinity so I think it's fair to also bring in the idea of the trinity in response. Thanks for engaging in  discussion!

When reflecting on the original Greek of Matt, 28:19, what is meant by...in the name of the Father and the ... Are Father, Son & HS names or titles?
As already stated in the answers already provided, "in the name of" means "by the authority of", etc, etc... and again, as already stated, we are talking "titles", not "names", when it comes to Father, Son and Holy Spirit.
...in the name of the Father and the Son and the Holy Spirit...
is known collectively as the "baptismal formula". What is not collectively, or even generally known, is that this formula, as it were, may well have not been in the original Matthew text, which by many an account, or even authority (see link below) was actually written in Hebrew. Consequently, this said formula may have been surreptitiously added by what amounts to unholy, trinitarian biased copyists, in an inauspicious attempt to advance their theology.
Further more, in Israelite times, names were not mere labels. They meant something. For example the name of Isaac, "Laughter," recalled the laughter of his aged parents when they first heard that they were to have a child. (Genesis 17:17, 19; 18:12) Esau's name meant "Hairy," describing a physical characteristic. His other name, Edom, "Red," or "Ruddy," was a reminder that he sold his birthright for a dish of red stew. (Genesis 25:25, 30-34; 27:11; 36:1) And so on and so on... Similarly, but certainly not unremarkably, God's name, represented by the four lettered Tetragrammaton, YHWH or JHVH, which appears almost 7000 times in the original "Old Testament," or Hebrew scriptures, means "He Causes to Become". The Son's name, commonly known as Jesus, in English bible translations at least, in Hebrew was something like Yeshua (or perhaps Yehoshua) and in Greek as I.e.sous, means "Jehovah's Salvation". But, when it comes to the name of the so called Holy Spirit, we are all, commoners and theologians alike, at a loss as to what  that all important name might indeed be. It would only stand to reason that if the so called third, equal in all respects, spiritual personage of the "Godhead" was indeed a person, as opposed to a spiritual force then "He" would have an all important name. The fact that "He" doesn't should be very telling to everyone. The Hebrew word ruach ha-kodesh must in actual fact refer to the divine force, quality, and influence of not only the Father but also the Son. Much less a title.
For those who want to check out the link I hinted at, above, one only needs to check out the following: https://jamestabor.com/how-does-ibn-shapruts-hebrew-matthew-compare-with-greek-matthew/

This is factually incorrect - there is no basis for any allegation that Matt 28:199 was either added or changed.  See https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/12794/was-the-text-of-matthew-2819-changed

The Dead Sea Scrolls were all completed before Matthew was written - we should not expect to find it there!!

Tell me - does the fact that Jesus is not mentioned in the dead sea scrolls mean that Jesus did not exist.  Why make the DSS the arbiter of truth?  All of Mark and Luke are absent from the DDS too!  Does that make them invalid?  You will need to document the quote from Matthew.

JHVH? There is no J in the Hebrew alphabet.

@Dottard - I have just deleted my comments, which suggested that portions of Matthew were found in the DSS. I was incorrect, which I realized once I went over my notes. I also edited out my answers last paragraph.

OK - so now what is your objection to my answer?

@Dottard - What do you mean? I stated what my objection was to your answer under your own answer. I would strongly suggest that you check out the link I gave at the bottom of my answer, as it is now, after removal of last sentence, and regard Tabor's video 19 mins, 40 secs in, in particular. But for context's sake, you should watch the first 30 mins ideally, to see what he is really all about. George Howards book of "The Hebrew Gospel of Matthew" (2nd Edition), argues that Shem Tov's Matthew comes from a much earlier Hebrew text/s that were later translated into Greek.

There is no evidence for Matthew or the baptismal formula being composed in Hebrew - can you produce its text?

Tabor says that George Howard's book (2nd Edition) is unfortunately no longer in print, nor are the earlier Hebrew texts as referred to by Shem Tov, or is it Tob, still in evidence, if my memory serves me correctly.

Can you tell me the all important name of the HS, what happened to that text??

Overview
Matthew 28 (ESV):

16 Now the eleven disciples went to Galilee, to the mountain to which Jesus had directed them. 17 And when they saw him they worshiped him, but some doubted. 18 And Jesus came and said to them, “All authority in heaven and on earth has been given to me. 19 Go therefore and make disciples of all nations, baptizing them in [or, into] the name of the Father and of the Son and of the Holy Spirit, (εἰς τὸ ὄνομα τοῦ πατρὸς καὶ τοῦ υἱοῦ καὶ τοῦ ἁγίου πνεύματος) 20 teaching them to observe all that I have commanded you. And behold, I am with you always, to the end of the age.”

Observations:

The command is given to the eleven disciples. They are not called apostles, but the article, οἱ δὲ ἕνδεκα with [the] eleven, means the remaining eleven who were called apostles.
They worshipped Jesus before hearing His instruction.
Jesus claimed to have all authority in heaven and on earth.
Using His authority Jesus instructed the eleven to go which means they were sent.
They were sent to πάντα τὰ ἔθνη all the Gentiles, not all nations. Since baptism is an individual experience, it would be impossible to baptize a nation.
They were to teach all Jesus had taught them.
They were to baptize.

There are at least four things which demonstrate the deity of Jesus.

The eleven worship Jesus. The testimony of John in Revelation, confirms he understood Jesus was God: I, John, am the one who heard and saw these things. And when I heard and saw them, I fell down to worship at the feet of the angel who showed them to me, but he said to me, “You must not do that! I am a fellow servant with you and your brothers the prophets, and with those who keep the words of this book. Worship God.” (Revelation 22:8-9) The evidence is two-fold. First the eleven worship. Second, Jesus fails to stop them.
Jesus claimed to have all authority in heaven and on earth. Only God has such authority.
The eleven were to teach what Jesus instructed. This is a consequence of having all authority. The eleven are not to teach the Mosaic Law. They are to teach what Jesus had instructed. Only God had the authority to issue such a command.
The promise to be with them always is a promise only God could make.

The Name
The name is written with the article τὸ ὄνομα. This means there is one name. The baptism is to be into τοῦ πατρὸς καὶ τοῦ υἱοῦ καὶ τοῦ ἁγίου πνεύματος. When items are listed with the article separated using the conjunction καὶ the grammatical construction means there are three separate and distinct, and all three must be present. Father, Son, Holy Spirit are neither names or titles. They are individually and equally present when baptism as Jesus instructs is done.
The phrase τοῦ πατρὸς καὶ τοῦ υἱοῦ καὶ τοῦ ἁγίου πνεύματος demands the presence of all three. One name, Jesus Christ does this. Jesus Christ is the name of the Son who is one with the Father (John 10:30) who sends the Holy Spirit in Jesus' name (John 14:26).
Acts 2:38:

And Peter said to them, “Repent and be baptized every one of you in the name of Jesus Christ for the forgiveness of your sins, and you will receive the gift of the Holy Spirit.


The deity of Jesus is not in question. He is after all the "only-begotten" (not made) of God. Authority had to be given (obviously by God) to Jesus. The promise to be with them always is easy for Jesus to give, seeing as he, himself, has deity. "The name", can mean something other than a personal name. When in English, we say, "in the name of the law," or "in the name of common sense," we have no ref. to a person as such. In Acts 2:38 and even elsewhere in Acts, the so called 3 persons are not all in evidence. The HS is even gifted, like a present, meaning "active force" is exalted.
